# How to explain what Event Listeners actually are?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm working on an article about event handling in JavaScript and though I think I have a relatively good understanding of the event model of the DOM, I find it hard to describe the concept of event listeners from a technical point of view!

The method addEventListener, as the name indicates, adds an event listener to a given object, by taking three arguments, first the type of the event, second the callback and the last one for capturing being optional and defaulting to false.

So far, so good, but how would you answer the question, what an event listener actually *is*?

As far as I understand the specification of the EventTarget interface, there must be some separate interface EventListener, to be inherited by the callback, containing a method handleEvent, which takes the occurring Event as parameter and, in case the event type and event phase match with the *somehow* stored values from the call of the addEventListener method, invokes callback.

But even if this interpretation was right, it nevertheless would be more of a vague description than a precise explanation of what's going on under the hood.

I've read a bunch of articles and tutorials concerning this topic, but they all seem to treat this thing as some kind of blackbox, by only describing what happens on the surface without providing details about the actual implementation.

So, it therefore would be great if someone could give me an insightful explanation about how this method works *internally*.

**EDIT**

Well, it seems like the method addEventListener actually *is* a blackbox and its specifications are indeed completely implementation dependend, so there maybe is just no way to tell how this model really works.

Interesting is though, that Firefox throws a TypeError for the property *handleEvent* not being callable, if you invoke addEventListener with a second argument that isn't a function-object and the event fires, while IE and Opera just ignore this.

However, I think this is not nearly enough evidence to assume that every function in JavaScript secretly inherits this method from an EventListener interface, just to be invoked in case the function serves as a callback for the addEventListener method.

So it could be, that the *event listener* really is just the callback with some hidden methods an properties that implement the required logic to handle the incoming event, but it could also be implemented in a completely different way...

Comment: An event listener is a function.

Comment: How it works internally is … internal. The specifics depend on the implementation. It's irrelevant unless you want to work on the source code of the JavaScript engine.

Comment: @Quentin Well, you're right when you say it is irrelevant for the usage of this method, and if I was writing a simple tutorial I wouldn't even try to go more into depth here, but for this article, I thought it would be interesting to describe how this method actually works, at least to the point, where things are really becoming implementation dependend. I'm not even sure if the description I gave within my question is fully right, as I couldn't find any hint concerning handleEvent or the EventListener interface in the dev-tools of my browser...

Comment: In Chrome and IE, if you enter `document.addEventListener` into the console and hit return, they both say: `function addEventListener() { [native code] }` - note the "native code" part - this function call _is_ the point where it becomes implementation dependent.

Comment: If you want to know how it is implemented v8 is open source as is chrome, you could just look at the source code. https://github.com/v8/v8